# input field model value is undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
 <ion-view cache-view="false">
  <ion-content class="has-header has-smallsubheader" >
  <form name="$root.deliveryDetails" action="#">
  <div>
  <div class="paddingOnSides">
   <p><input type="number" name="usermobileNumber" ng-model="userEnteredMobileNumber" />                                                 </p> 
 <div>
 <span class="button" ng-click="checkRegisteredUsers()">Verify</span>
 </div>
  </div>
  </ion-view>
 </ion-content>
```

controller:

```
$scope.checkRegisteredUsers = function(){
  console.log($scope.userEnteredMobileNumber)  //gives undefined
}
```

I have tried using an object instead of a primitive in field`ng-model` like `formData.userEnteredMobileNumber` instead but I still get undefined.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you pass the object in the function? $scope.checkRegistedUsers = function(object) { // code to log user number }

Comment: I can, but passing variables attached to ng-model does not sound like a good idea. Would be redundant , isn't it?

Comment: ye I guess, the only other thing I can think of is that it's not initiated in the controller (would at least remove undefiened error)

Comment: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cant-access-form-on-scope/679/31 thread I guess talks closely of the problem but have not been able to get it working yet. Could you please check? You might be able to help me understand what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Created a sample plunkr with the same code and works fine.

```
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <form name="$root.deliveryDetails" action="#">
      <div>
         <div class="paddingOnSides">
            <p><input type="number" name="usermobileNumber" ng-model="userEnteredMobileNumber" /></p>
            <div>
               <span class="button" ng-click="checkRegisteredUsers()">Verify</span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <p>Mobile {{userEnteredMobileNumber}}!</p>
      </div>
   </form>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LNxCpKy7yn3HttI2Tc3B?p=preview